# Bootstrap or other resampling techniques in meta-analysis

Tags: bootstrap, inference, meta-analysis, sensitivity-analysis

I am conducting a network meta-analysis of clinical trials on cardioprotective drugs in patients undergoing chemotherapy (see PROSPERO protocol [CRD42015029915](http://www.crd.york.ac.uk/PROSPERO/display_record.asp?ID=CRD42015029915)), and I was wondering how much it would make sense to add, as sensitivity analysis, bootstrapped effect estimates. Other suitable approaches could be to use jackknife resampling.

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, and [a web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bootstrapped+meta-analysis&t=ffsb&ia=web) seems to show a couple of previous examples. [Or here.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=bootstrap+meta-analysis)